# React app that runs locally crashes on Heroku: H10 "App crashed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

My React application runs fine locally, but crashes on Heroku. Here are the logs:

```
2020-09-02T22:40:08.920880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=corona-charts.herokuapp.com request_id=d493717f-dd9d-4a20-ad1f-76f877acbd8d fwd="174.67.238.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-02T22:41:00.972039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=corona-charts.herokuapp.com request_id=28651997-4ff3-43ed-810b-6059f0dfae6e fwd="17
```

You can find all the code for my React app here: https://github.com/SirIsaacNeutron/us-corona-charts. The Heroku link is http://corona-charts.herokuapp.com.

I added the "https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git" buildpack that I apparently needed to add, but the app still crashes. Here are the buildpacks I used:
[the buildpacks I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ixt2.png)

The only cause of this problem that I can think of is the charts I am using. In the past, sometimes my local app crashed if I hovered over them while starting the app, although I haven't had this problem at all on my local version for a while.

I really appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Comment: do you have a backend that you're deploying as well? or is it just your react app

Comment: @azium It's just my React app. There is no backend that I created; I'm using data from covidtracking.com for the app.

Comment: use something like netlify https://www.netlify.com/ it's designed for static assets like react app

Comment: @azium :D it works on netlify! It's weird to me that Heroku can't seem to handle my simple React app, but oh well. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @azium wait, there now seems to be a new issue even though the site was working just fine before. In my console I see: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/ny/daily.json' from origin 'https://us-corona-charts.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I don't think there's anything I can actually do about this from what little research I just did... oh well.

Answer (score 1):

When using create-react-app and deploying to

1. dont delete the favicon.ico and manifest.json
2. also in package.json above scripts insert "engines": {
   "npm": "6.x",
   "node": "12.x"
   },

//NOTE CHECK YOUR NODE AND NPM VERSIONS BY TYPING npm -v and node -v for accurate versions//

Dont add other scripts or change the start, build scripts!

This should clear all h10 errors when deploying to heroku, if they dont i suggest you create a new directory and copy your files there and start over, this link is a great guide to deploy

https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f

Comment: Thanks to @wwitshadows for the answer, in my case was a mix os solution but the most important I think was DON'T DELETE the favicon and manifest at first, and other solution was include in settings the build pack 
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git#v9.0.0
in the last version 9.0

Comment: Glad that helped! i had the same problem not long ago.